# Правописание слова ТОРФОПЕРЕГНОЙНЫЙ

Tags: орфография

Наткнулась на слово ТОРФОПЕРЕГНОЙНЫЙ. Никак не могу привязать его написание к известным мне правилам русской орфографии. По всем известным мне нормам, это слово должно писаться через дефис. Найти исчерпывающую аргументацию слитного написания не могу

Comment: Это "перегной торфа" или смесь торфа с перегноем чего-то другого?

Answer (score 1):

Это прилагательное пишется слитно в соответствии со следующим правилом:

> Пишутся слитно сложные прилагательные, образованные от слитно
> пишущихся сложных существительных, ср.: железобетон → железобетонный;
> паровоз → паровозный; микроволны → микроволновый.

Существительное *торфоперегной* пишется слитно по такому правилу:

> Пишутся слитно сложные существительные, образованные с помощью
> соединительной гласной, напр.: водовоз, земледелие.

Термин *торфоперегной* используется в узкоспециальной литературе и не попало в общие словари, но это не помешало широко распространиться образованному от него прилагательному.

Comment: Предполагала такой ответ, но не нашла слова ПЕРЕГНОЙ в словарях.

Comment: А в каком словаре Вы не нашли слова "перегной"? Я советую пользоваться [академическими словарями](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x) Грамоты. Как видите, в орфографическом словаре Лопатина и в толковом словаре Кузнецова это слово есть.

Comment: Посмотрел ещё толковые словари Ефремовой, Ожегова, Даля, Ушакова — это слово есть во всех словарях.